# How do I order by NULLS LAST if my database doesn't support it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, order-by, null

```
Select      FullName, Login 
FROM        [User]
ORDER BY    FullName desc, login asc
```

#### Results

```
FullName                      Login
----------------------------- ------------------------------
M...... H.........            mh..@...com
A.... H.....                  ad..@...com
NULL                          and..@...com
NULL                          ben..@...com
NULL                          roc..@...com
```

#### What I want

```
FullName                      Login
----------------------------- ------------------------------
A.... H.....                  ad..@...com
M...... H.........            mh..@...com
NULL                          and..@...com
NULL                          ben..@...com
NULL                          roc..@...com
```

I want the full name in abc order desc and same with login, but I want all nulls to go to the bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 Select      FullName, Login 
 FROM        [User]
 ORDER BY    CASE WHEN FullName IS NULL THEN 'ZZZZZZZ' ELSE FullName END, login asc
```

Comment: Your `CASE` could be shortened with `COALESCE`.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree. `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` would have been shorter.  And I do like your answer better.  It's better to pull the NULL piece out entirely.

Comment: Be careful of this pattern though: it can force extra index scans or a spool to tempdb. For small reaultsets the spool isn't an issue but it can be a significant performance issue otherwise. Even the `UNION ALL` version has the same problem though. As usual, benchmark against realistic data to make sure the performance is acceptable.

Comment: @DavidSpillett by preference I'm going to a) sort it at the application layer, b) sort the result set not the query itself (depending of course)

Comment: @DavidSpillett I didn't find that with the  `union all` here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886857/sql-server-order-by-date-and-nulls-last/5886975#5886975 just gives a seek of the `null` and a seek of the `not null` and no sort or any tempdb usage is needed as long as there is a supporting index.

Answer (score 29):

There is a (closed) connect item requesting support for [`NULLS LAST`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/329337/nulls-ordering-nulls-first-nulls-last-sql-2012) in SQL Server.

A couple of other ways would be

```
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN FullName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
        FullName,
        Login
```

I prefer this as it doesn't rely on hardcoding a string that it is assumed no legitimate data will sort after. I'd rather not have to consider that on some case sensitive collations z sorts before Z and on others the reverse applies, will that be an issue? Similarly will "[Željko Ivanek](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%BDeljko_Ivanek)" sort before "ZZZZZZZ" reliably on all collations? Are there other characters from other languages that might exist in a name and sort after "Z"?

A potentially more efficient solution if there is an index on `FullName, Login` (as it hopefully will avoid a sort)

```
CREATE TABLE [User]
  (
     FullName VARCHAR(100),
     Login    VARCHAR(100),
     INDEX IX (FullName,Login) /*Use separate create index if < 2014*/
  );

WITH T
     AS (SELECT 1 AS Grp,
                *
         FROM   [User]
         WHERE  FullName IS NOT NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS Grp,
                *
         FROM   [User]
         WHERE  FullName IS NULL)
SELECT FullName,
       Login
FROM   T
ORDER  BY Grp,
          FullName,
          Login
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Being an old thread I assume it's sorted.
I've tried all other methods, none work on Microsoft SQL Server, except this
(only tested with column 'FullName').

```
Select  FullName, Login, ISNULL(FullName, 'ZZZ') AS SORTED
FROM   [User]
ORDER BY SORTED
```